# How to produce an array from a function in r?

Tags: r

X and Y are distributed as poisson RV's with lambda 10 and 20 respectively. I need to create a function sample() that generates n realisations of (X, Y)  and produces an nx2 array.

So far I have done:

```
sample=function()          
{
  X=rpois(1,10)
  Y=rpois(1,20)
}
```

How do I then produce an array?

Comment: It's not clear what your expected output should look like. Are you just asking for `c(X,Y)`, or perhaps `matrix(c(X,Y),ncol=2,byrow=FALSE)` or even `cbind(X,Y)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fred_sample <- function(n){
  X <- rpois(n, 10)
  Y <- rpois(n, 20)
  matrix(c(X, Y), n)
}
```

A few points:

1. I'd avoid naming your function sample or you will end up masking the base function named sample.
2. You need to pass `n` to sample if you want it to generate an `n` by `2` array.